# How to test SMTP email sending capability, locally?

Tags: smtp

I need to test SMTP email sending capability that I just added to my java app. So far, I only tested it using my private Gmail account. It works fine.

Now I would like to test various settings: SSL, no SSL, TLS, no TLS, change ports, require authenticaton or no authentication, etc. This is because this app will soon go to customers, and I presume they all have different SMTP settings. I'd like to make sure the app works in majority of cases.

How should I test my app email sending capabilities?

Should I set-up some SMTP server on my local Windows 7 machine?

Which way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can test all the possible combinations is to set up or connect to servers that use them all. There is simply no other way. If you're going to test this on your workstation then don't set it up under Windows 7. Install Virtualbox (or whatever other virtualisation system you like) and install virtual machines that have the various configurations you want to test against.

Comment: Thanks. Once I set up let's say Linux inside a virtual machine, shouldn't I be able to set up SMTP and configure it the way I want?

Comment: Correct. I suggest you start by creating a base install of whatever OS you want to use, together with an SMTP server, then save a snapshot of it. You can then revert to that snapshot each time you need a new configuration and just make the required changes, rather than having to do a new install each time. It there is a chance you may want to repeat these tests in the future you could also export and save each configured version before reverting to the snapshot.

Comment: OK. Shouldn't I be able to reconfigure SMTP without reinstalling whole OS? Isn't there a settings where I can define SSL or TLS for example? Does that really require total reinstall?

Comment: Perhaps you should reread my previous comment. Yes, you can reconfigure but by taking it back to the snapshot you will have a cleaner base to work with.

Answer (score 1):

[hMailServer](https://hmailserver.com/) open source e-mail server for Windows is great for this.

The mail handler itself is a Windows service. The admin control panel is a GUI Windows app. You can run any combination of configs at the same time (mail protocol, port, authentication, encryption, forwarding, etc). After changing a setting in the admin program, it will stop and re-start the service for you, instantly.

Installing on the same machine is okay. Installing on another machine in your network is better. Ideally the server should be on a different IP address than the client, but it works fine on the same IP address.